# Counter modifying noun with という

Tags: grammar, counters

> ... 何百というふくろうが四方八方に飛び交う光景が見られました。
> You could see the sight of hundreds of owls flying in every direction.

I'm intrigued by 何百というふくろう. Why is という used here?

I get very confused when it comes to numbers and counters in Japanese.  Why could it not be just

> 何百**の**ふくろう?

Or, maybe since we're counting birds, it should be

> 何百羽のふくろう?

Or even, adverbially,

> ふくろうが何百飛び交う.

Which among these examples is grammatical and what are the differnces of nuance between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

何百というふくろう is very close to 何百ものふくろう:

- 数百(羽)のふくろう
  several hundred owls
- 何百(羽)ものふくろう
  hundreds of owls
- 何百(羽)というふくろう
  hundreds of owls

Although the latter two are translated into English the same way, I think the という version is a little more emphatic and literary, and often has a stronger connotation of "countless". I think it's best to remember this as a common grammar pattern rather than asking why. (Grammatically, 何百という is a relative clause that modifies ふくろう, so a super-literal translation is "owls to which one says hundreds".)

You can say the same thing adverbially:

- ふくろうが数百(羽)飛び交っている。
  Several hundred owls are flying about.
- ふくろうが何百(羽)**も**飛び交っている。
  Hundreds of owls are flying about.

In this pattern, 何 must be used with も, so 何百のふくろう and ふくろうが何百飛び交う are both ungrammatical. (You can say 何百のふくろう if you are asking "how many hundreds of owls?", though.)

**EDIT:** An important difference from ～もの is that you can use という only with 何. For example, you can say 83羽ものふくろう ("as many as eighty three owls") but not 83羽というふくろう.