# ５個入りという usage, and nuance?

Tags: grammar, translation, manga

I just saw this [thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97897/counter-modifying-noun-with-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86) which might be answering my question, but as I am unsure, I would like to clarify why という is being used here? Does anyone have any ideas?

[image][Counter modifying noun with という](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97897/counter-modifying-noun-with-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86)

Comment: Unrelated, but could someone also please comment on what 感 means here?

Comment: same as 感じ as far as I can tell, it's used as a suffix here. e.g. ボリューム感を有する, to have a voluminous feeling.

Answer (score 2):

という has various usages, and という in your sentence is explained in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52003/5010). That is, 5個入り ("containing 5 pieces") is working as a explanation of ボリューム感. So a literal translation is "voluminous feeling of having-five(-in-a-package)!".

Although 5個入り happens to contain a number, your sentence has almost nothing to do with the `何 + number + という` explained in the question you linked. This construction must be used always with 何 (e.g., 何十という人, 何万円という金額, 何千万キロという距離).

Answer (score -1):

As a meaning of [という](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86/#jn-154743) itself, rather than a pattern, the one in question and the linked question (何百というふくろう) are the same:

> ３ 数量を表す語に付いて、…に達する、…にも及ぶ、などの意を表す。「八千メートル―高所」「何万人―観光客」

It means something like *as many as*: *as many as five-piece set* (and *as many as hundreds of owls*)

---

Most probably the phrase refers to [薄皮シリーズ](https://www.yamazakipan.co.jp/brand/usukawa/index.html), which was recently reduced to 4-piece pack as seen in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/Ito1973/status/1609423020615143424?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1609423020615143424%7Ctwgr%5E8b2647d8b4d2641fb09bffa9190d7976a773c4b0%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fkokopyon.net%2Fblog-entry-64954.html).

Comment: その「という」とは別物だと思います。「結構するのに2個入りという割高感」「頑張ったのに23点という報われない感」みたいな言い方も普通に成立するので、質問で聞かれている「という」自体に数量の多さを強調する働きはないと思います。

Comment: @naruto それらは少なさを強調する使い方だと思います。

Comment: 「お手頃価格なのに他社の特盛と同サイズというボリューム感」「頑張ったのに不合格という報われない感」のようにそもそも数字関係なしにも使えます。要するに質問の「という」は偶然数字が前に来ているだけで、「数量を表す語に付いて数値の大きさを強調するトイウ」とは無関係だということです。「何万人もの観光客」とは言えても「5個入りものボリューム感」とは言いませんし。

Comment: @naruto 「同サイズ」は広い意味では数量表現ですし、「不合格」については質問にある例とずれると思います。コメントされている点は、そもそも辞書がどこまで完全か・ある用例が辞書にある特定の定義にどこまで当てはまるかという事についての意見の違いであって、自分としては質問にある例（五個入りというボリューム感・何百というふくろう）が数量の強調を意味する「という」であると解釈して問題ないと考えます。

Comment: 質問ですが「1袋5個入りというボリューム感」「1袋2個入りという割高感」「1袋3個入りという妥当感」といった表現が何らかの数量強調表現だとして、ではこれらの非強調バージョンは何になるのでしょうか。「何千羽という鳥」や「数千羽もの鳥」の非強調バージョンは「数千羽の鳥」ですが、それに該当する表現はあるでしょうか。個人的には「鳥」と違って「ボリューム感」はそれ自体を数えたり計測したりできないので、「1袋2個入りの割高感」ではなく「1袋2個入りという割高感」と接続する方が単純に自然であり、どちらかが数字の大小をより強調しているという感じはしません。

Comment: @naruto それはむしろボリューム感や割高感といった単語が自然に強調を要求するからであって、自分には「五個入りのボリューム感」は特に問題ないです（ボリューム感をより文字通り五個入りの与えるボリュームに関する印象、ととらえれば）。narutoさんの回答に従えば、「1億円という金額」は強調出ないという事になると思いますが（「何・・・という」ではないので）、自分にはそうは思えません。感覚の問題だと思います。

Comment: 「何+単位+という」ではない具体的な数値だと「1億円という大金」と同じように「1億円という端金」とも「765mという特に高くも低くもない山」とも言え、それ自体に大きさを強調する意味を感じづらいのでこの部分の辞書の定義は微妙だなと思っているのですが、ここはまあ感覚の違いかもしれませんね。長くなるのでこのくらいにします、ありがとうございました。（なお念のため、downvoteは自分ではないです）